# how do i append from one list to another sequentially

Tags: python, list

so i have a deck of cards here. the program gives you a random card from the deck. I made a list "popcorn" im trying to get that list to append to each card, the amount being entered in raw input. I got it to append the first item of "popcorn" list but cant get it to append sequentially. any help would be awesome
http://pastebin.com/Zh8FQqf6

Answer (score 1):

you can use [list.extend](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

> L.extend(iterable) -- extend list by appending elements from the iterable

```
>a = [1, 5, 7]  
>b = [2, 6, 9]
>a.extend(b)
>a
[1, 5, 7, 2, 6, 9]
```